# Koalas diff not giving matching results like pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

I have a pandas, koalas df as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],'b': [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],'c': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]})
```

Im trying to Generate diff with previous column as below

```
df.diff(axis=1)
    a  b   c
0 NaN  0   0
1 NaN -1   3
2 NaN -1   7
3 NaN -1  13
4 NaN  0  20
5 NaN  2  28
```

when i try to generate the same in Koalas as below

```
Kdf = ks.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],'b': [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],'c': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]})

kdf.diff(axis=1) # gives error as(not implemented axis should be 0 or index)
```

Also tried defining as kdf.diff(periods=1, axis=0) the results are not identical with pandas

```
   a   b    c
0 NaN  NaN  NaN
1 1.0  0.0  3.0
2 1.0  1.0  5.0
3 1.0  1.0  7.0
4 1.0  2.0  9.0
5 1.0  3.0  11.0
```

As of now Im converting to pandas and back to koalas(this gives matching results like pandas output)

```
Ndf = ks.DataFrame(kdf.to_pandas().diff(axis=1))
Ndf
  a  b   c
0 NaN  0  0
1 NaN -1  3
2 NaN -1  7
3 NaN -1  13
4 NaN  0  20
5 NaN  2  28
```

Please suggest if there is better way of achieving the same functionality through Koalas without converting it to pandas df.

Thank you